# Intent is not triggered in android searchview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, searchview

Here is my code for `searchview` in android.Search option is visible on the `toolbar` but when a text and entered and searched it does not trigger `SearchActivity`.

**xml/searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/label"
    android:hint="@string/search" >
</searchable>
```

**menu/menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.welcomecure.searchview">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

          </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
              android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
              android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
          android:name=".SearchActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">

          <!-- to identify this activity as "searchable" -->
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>

          <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
       </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
 }
}
```

**SearchActivity.java**

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //use the query to search
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Activity is named `SearchActivity`, but you declared `SearchResultsActivity` in manifest:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
     android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
```

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html):

> To declare the searchable activity for an activity's search dialog,
>   add a  element inside the respective activity's 
>   element. The  element must include the android:value
>   attribute that specifies the searchable activity's class name and the
>   android:name attribute with a value of
>   "android.app.default_searchable".

Comment: Hehe! Form of your question was quite good though. Feel free to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the same activity name from the calling activity, you used SearchActivity to show the search result, try to use the same activity name

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

          </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
              android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
              android:value=".SearchActivity" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this programmatically.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { // this is triggered when you press the key search from keyboard.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { // this is triggered when you change your search text. 
            return true;
        }
    });
```